# Which is natural, fall into, fit into, belong to a category?

Tags: word-choice

Which is natural, *fall into*, *fit into*, *belong to* a category?

1. Tigers **fall into** the category of "Big Cat".
2. Tigers **fit into** the category of "Big Cat".
3. Tigers **belong to** the category of "Big Cat".

Which one is better?

Comment: You could check on Google - try "belongs in the category" too.

Comment: I'd say the "most natural" (certainly, the *simplest*) is just *'Tiger' **is in** the category 'Big Cat'*. But all OP's variations (and many more) are "valid", and I think it's just a matter of opinion/personal style which to use in any given context.

Answer (score 2):

None of the predicates are "better" than any other one.
They're **different**, not better. They refer to different metaphors.
All of them refer to a structural part-whole relation, evoking different frames

- *fall into* evokes a 3-dimensional container metaphor in a gravity field
- *fit into* evokes a puzzle metaphor (2-D) or a building metaphor (3-D)
- *belong to* evokes a possession metaphor

There are some problems with the noun phrases, however. If you're speaking about species in general, you're using [generic noun phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), and just plain *tiger* isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1):

"Belongs to" feels more definite.  Meaning that if "Big Cat" was only in that category I would use "belongs to".

"Fit into" and "Fall into" invokes visions maybe not fitting the category definition exactly but it works.